# no live upstreams while connecting to upstream

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to set up reverse proxy using nginx. The thing is i want to redirect to umami login page when go to localhost. But i am getting 502 bad gateway.I am not  sure i have correctly configured the nginx.
Here is my docker-compose.yml looks like:

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./my_proxy.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
  umami:
    image: ghcr.io/mikecao/umami:postgresql-latest
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://umami:umami@db:5432/umami
      DATABASE_TYPE: postgresql
      HASH_SALT: 1234567890
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
    networks:
      - nginx-net
  db:
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: umami
      POSTGRES_USER: umami
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: umami
    volumes:
      - ./sql/schema.postgresql.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema.postgresql.sql:ro
      - umami-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always
    networks:
      - nginx-net
volumes:
  umami-db-data:
  conf:
  vhost:
  html:
  dhparam:
  certs:

networks:
  nginx-net:
    external:
      name: nginx-net
```

Here is my_proxy.conf which i am mounting over default.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/login;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}
```

Here is sql folder link that i have used.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lvyLUve0SGpT1tXlsVoFwPmbmb75n8ER/view?usp=sharing

Here is the screenshort of log file.

[log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nU0ZL.png)

```
2022/12/13 17:58:09 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2022/12/13 17:58:09 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.23.2
2022/12/13 17:58:09 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6) 
2022/12/13 17:58:09 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.15.0-56-generic
2022/12/13 17:58:09 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1024:524288
2022/12/13 17:58:09 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2022/12/13 17:58:09 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 21
2022/12/13 17:58:09 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 22
2022/12/13 17:58:09 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 23
2022/12/13 17:58:09 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 24
2022/12/13 17:58:09 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 25
2022/12/13 17:58:09 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 26
2022/12/13 17:58:09 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 27
2022/12/13 17:58:09 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 28
2022/12/13 17:58:10 [error] 21#21: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.20.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /nginx_status HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/loginnginx_status", host: "172.18.0.1"
2022/12/13 17:58:10 [warn] 21#21: *1 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 172.20.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /nginx_status HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/loginnginx_status", host: "172.18.0.1"
2022/12/13 17:58:10 [error] 21#21: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.20.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /nginx_status HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/loginnginx_status", host: "172.18.0.1"
2022/12/13 17:58:10 [warn] 21#21: *1 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 172.20.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /nginx_status HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/loginnginx_status", host: "172.18.0.1"
172.20.0.1 - - [13/Dec/2022:17:58:10 +0000] "GET /nginx_status HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" "-"
172.20.0.1 - - [13/Dec/2022:17:58:20 +0000] "GET /nginx_status HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" "-"
2022/12/13 17:58:20 [error] 22#22: *4 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.20.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /nginx_status HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/loginnginx_status", host: "172.18.0.1"
2022/12/13 17:58:20 [warn] 22#22: *4 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 172.20.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /nginx_status HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/loginnginx_status", host: "172.18.0.1"
2022/12/13 17:58:20 [error] 22#22: *4 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.20.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /nginx_status HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/loginnginx_status", host: "172.18.0.1"
2022/12/13 17:58:20 [warn] 22#22: *4 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 172.20.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /nginx_status HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/loginnginx_status", host: "172.18.0.1"
```

Suggest how do i correct this?

Comment: Please don't post text that you could just copy&paste as screenshots. You are just making it harder to extract information out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Every container has its own network. By providing `localhost` as the backend address nginx tries to access this port inside its own container. You need to provide the other container instead:

```
proxy_pass http://umami:3000/login;
```

The name of the container is available as a "hostname" inside the other containers, so there should not be more to do than that.

You can remove the port definition for port 3000, it's only needed to access the port from outside the containers.